# Ba'al HaTanya on Echad Mi Yodeya

Tags: sources-mekorot, passover-seder-hagada

I heard from a Rav in a *shiur* that he saw written somewhere in the name of the [**Ba'al HaTanya**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shneur_Zalman_of_Liadi) an explanation for the song [*Echad Mi Yodeya*](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesach_Haggadah%2C_Nirtzah%2C_Echad_Mi_Yodea.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) at the end of the *Haggadah*. It seems a little incongruous to start counting seemingly random things to do with Judaism.

He explained it with a parable that when someone wants to show off how proud they are of their ancestry/heritage, they start showing various emblems and artifacts from their past. They show off this medallion, this ancient manuscript, these articles of clothing. That's what we're doing at the end of the *Haggadah*. After solidifying our relationship with Hashem, we contemplate how proud we are of our heritage. We start listing off things that make us special <sup>1</sup>. One G-d in Heaven. Two stone tablets. Three forefathers...etc.

Anyone know the source for this explanation? On a side note, in my attempts at finding this, I found that Lubavitch chassidim don't have the custom to say this song. I find it interesting then that there would be an explanation of it from their founder.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Rav admitted that 9 months of pregnancy and 11 stars in Yosef's dream need clarification why we're listing them.

Comment: Is your Rav a Lubavitcher? Why not simply contact him and ask what the actual source is?

Comment: @YaacovDeane the Rav I heard this from isn't a Lubavitcher, and I don't have access to him to ask

Comment: It's the expression "written somewhere" that is catching my attention. I haven't seen everything, but from the expression, it sounds more like something that could have been said by one of the later Rebbes in a talk related to Pesach as a side comment.